# iOS Simulator: Which folders can be safely deleted?

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, ios-simulator

My **iOS simulator folder** has a few folders which relate to older iOS versions (please refer to the screen shot below).

Can I safely delete all folders for iOS versions < 6 ?

In the user folder are also the folders `Media.previousInstall` and `Library.previousInstall`. Can the `*.previousInstall` folders be safely deleted too?

[image: iOS Simulator Folders]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no expert on this topic, but deleting these two folders didn't seem to have any impact on my iOS Simulator (with Xcode 4.5.1 under OS X 10.8.2).

However, both folders combined were only 22MB on my disk, so you don't really gain that much by deleting them. ;)